# Error Long Log Tags (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo un error pero no e encontrado como solucionarlo como tal si no solo como tapar el problema.

```
Log.e("APIComm:AssetsPropertyReader", e.toString());
```

Me marca el error,

> The loggin tag can be at most 23 characters, was 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que la longitud máxima es de 23 caracteres en un tag (etiqueta), de lo contrario obtendrás un [IllegalArgumentException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

La definición del tag (etiqueta) es:

> **tag** :  Se utiliza para identificar el origen de un mensaje de
>   registro. Por lo general, identifica la clase o actividad donde se
>   produce la llamada de registro.

**En este caso el problema es la longitud de tu tag  `"APIComm:AssetsPropertyReader"`, reduce a 23 caracteres o menos**, por ejemplo:

error:

```
Log.e("APIComm:AssetsPropertyReader", e.toString());
```

opción:

```
Log.e("APIComm:AssetsPropRead", e.toString());
```

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) puedes revisar lo comentado anteriormente.

Cabe comentar que en android 7.0 (Nougat), esta longitud ya no es preocupación, si defines en tu proyecto `targetSdk 24` podras sin problema agregar la cantidad de caracteres deseados en el `TAG`, de tu mensaje a mostrar en el `LogCat`.

Answer (score -1):

La solución te la dice en el mismo error, la etiqueta (tag) no puede tener mas de 23 caracteres. Osea, no puede tener mas de 23 letras, de lo contrario lanzara una excepción.

La etiqueta es el primer parametro que recibe la sentencia:

```
Log.i("etiqueta", "mensaje de error);
```

Tu problema se soluciona acortando la etiqueta. En vez de usar `APIComm:AssetsPropertyReader` puedes usar `APIComm:AssetsProperty`.

```
Log.e("APIComm:AssetsProperty", e.toString());
```